# R Select date range over multiple years and calculate mean of values

Tags: r, datetime

I have a data frame with hourly data running over 5 years. I want to calculate the hourly mean (i.e., the mean value for every hour of the day, 1:24) of values between two dates (e.g., 15-March to 15-Apr) over several years, and compare that to the hourly mean of the last year.

Here is an example of the data:

```
start = as.POSIXct(strptime("2011-01-01 01:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))
end   = as.POSIXct(strptime("2016-01-01 01:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))
df = data.frame(DateTime = seq(from = start, to = end,by = "hours"))
df$value = runif(nrow(df))

Start_Period = "03-15"
End_Period = "04-15"
```

The output should look like:

```
Hour   mean(2011-2014) mean(2015)
1      0.3             0.5
...
24     0.8             0.6
```

Comment: If the starting is 03-15, do you need mean for 2011-2014

Comment: the mean of 2011-03-15 to 2011-04-15, 2012-03-15 to 2012-04-15, 2013-03-15 to 2013-04-15, 2014-03-15 to 2014-04-15. Compared to the mean of 2015-03-15 to 2015-04-15

Comment: you meant year-day and not year-month for 03-15?

Comment: year-month-day:  2011-Mar-15 to 2011-Apr-15...

Comment: @llik can you please check whether the solution below works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `filter` based on the 'start', 'end' date, then do a group by 'hour' 'year' and get the `mean`

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)   
df %>%
    filter((day(DateTime) >= 15 & month(DateTime) == 3)|
          (day(DateTime) <= 15 & month(DateTime) ==  4))   %>% 
    group_by(hour = hour(DateTime), year = year(DateTime)) %>% 
    summarise(value = mean(value))
```